# npm install on cleaned project does not 'update'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, semantic-versioning, npm-update

I have the following scenario:

- project with installed node_modules
- work directory is emptied
- project is freshly cloned from git
- npm install is run

I have a dependency required as `~1.0.0` in package.json. This dependency was previously installed in version `1.0.1`. It has now newer versions, e.g. `1.0.2`, available but still gets installed as `1.0.1` by `npm install`. But I want the dependency to get updated within the range that I specified.

Why is that and how could I solve this? Would using `npm update` instead/ afterwards help?

BR
Chris

Comment: Do you say that in package.json it is mentioned as "~1.0.0"?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. If in case your problem is not resolved then user caret (^) symbol instead of tilde (~). Caret helps install the latest version.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? Are there other packages that have their own dependency requirements for the package that is stuck at 1.0.1?